# How to express a Spin Up in direction $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$ in terms of the $S_z$ basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, precession

So, In the question below, they've asked me to express the Spin Up in n Vector in terms of the $S_z$ basis. As shown in the question, the unit vector for $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$ is expressed as a function of the x and y basis vectors. My issue is I don't know how they managed to get the $\theta$ and azimuth angles from the function.

[image: Question]

I've managed to figure out that the Azimuthal angle is π/4. I'm completely lost as to how they got the Theta angle though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the most general spin state
$$
\vert +\rangle_n = \cos\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\theta \,\vert +\rangle_z + 
e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{1}{2}\theta\, \vert - \rangle_z \tag{1}
$$
and compute the average values
$$
\langle S_x\rangle =\sin\theta\cos\phi\, ,\quad
\langle S_y\rangle =\sin\theta\sin\phi\, ,\quad 
\langle S_z\rangle=\cos\theta\, . \tag{2}
$$
These are by definition the components of your $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$.  There remains to fix $\theta$ and $\phi$ so that (1) will produce the specific $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$ you want.

Alternatively, you could start with $\vert + \rangle_x$, i.e. the spin-up along $\hat x$, and rotate this about $\hat z$ so as to get $\vert +\rangle_n$.

You can connect both suggestions by as simple guess as to what angle $\theta$ will take you from the $\boldsymbol{\hat z}$ to $\boldsymbol{\hat x}$ directions, and then rotate about $\hat z$ as suggested to finally get the direction $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$

Comment: How would I use the equation n = (x + y)/sqrt(2) in all this?

Comment: What is $n_x, n_y,n_z$ for this vector?  As stated, $n_x=\langle S_x\rangle$ etc...

Comment: I'm still not seeing how the expected values connect in with all this. So if I were to express n-hat as a sum of expected values and then equate that (x + y)/sqrt(2), I could then somehow solve for the angles?

Comment: You want the "direction" of spin to be that of your vector $$\boldsymbol{\hat n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0)$$ so that your spin-up state is aligned with $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$ .  Thus, $\langle S_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ etc.

Comment: Right, I understand now. I then proceed to use those 3 relationships to solve for the angles. Thankyou!